# Magento dropdown in the left sidebar display incorrectly

Tags: magento

I tried to add several dropdown lists on the left sidebar on the site, they are all have similar settings in the "Catalog"->"Manage Attribute". I used Amasty for this site.

However, the odd thing is that one attribute: "School Name" does not display the same as the other three. All the other attributes (Brand, Size, Color) are fine.

Here is the screenshots:

Settings for the "School Name":
https://www.dropbox.com/s/81kjt5ab3l9dgg9/Capture1.PNG

How the attributes display on my site:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yff58b635mrn7cg/Capture.PNG

Is there something I've missed? How should I make the "School Name" display as dropdown as the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be referring to the documentation that came with the extension for questions such as these.

With the Amasty Improved Navigation extension (I'm assuming this is the one you're using), the display for the filters are managed under **Catalog > Improved Navigation > Filters**

From there, you can select your attribute **School Name** and change the **Display Type** field to **Drop-down list**.

[image: Amasty Improved Navigation]

Comment: Thanks Axel, your solution is much better! Yesterday I solved this by turning off the "Label" option in app\design\frontend\..\default\template\amshopby\attribute.phtml.